# TFS Tasks and bugs: Should I re-open a task if I find bugs?

Tags: tfs, agile

When a task is done, the developer closes it. The associated User story begins to be tested by the QA team.

My question is: Once a bug is found by the QA team, besides the fact that they open a bug, should they re-open the task and the associated User Story?

Using TFS 2012 and agile template

Comment: Which process template are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown by the workflow diagram for the User Story work item below, if "code complete and unit tests pass" then put into "Resolved" state.  If "Acceptance Tests fail", then put in "Active" state and re-assign to developer.  Only go to "Closed" state if "Acceptance tests pass".

Further info can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380634.aspx).

[image: State Diagram for User Story]

Answer (score 2):

*You should not close the user story until it has been completed. If there is still testing to be done then it has not been completed!*

I nice solution would be to create additional Tasks under the User Story for Testing. When Tests fail you should create the associated bug under the User Story and this will allow you to query User Stories that still have Bugs.